# Compute $\int_\Sigma \frac{1}{y^4} d\sigma$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Compute $$\int_\Sigma \frac{1}{y^4} d\sigma$$
where
$\sum = \left\{(x,y,z) \mid y\in [1,2], ~ y= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{z^2+x^2}}\right\}$.

First I parameterize the surface

$h(u,v) = (u, \frac{1}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}},v)$
So:

$h_u = (1, \frac{-u}{{(u^2+v^2)}^\frac 32},0)$

$h_v = (0, \frac{-v}{{(u^2+v^2)}^\frac 32},1)$

$\|h_u\times h_v\|= \sqrt{\frac{u^2}{{(u^2+v^2)}^3}+1+ \frac{v^2}{{(u^2+v^2)}^3}}$

The integral became:

$\int \int (u^2+v^2)^2\sqrt{\frac{u^2}{{(u^2+v^2)}^3}+1+ \frac{v^2}{{(u^2+v^2)}^3}}dudv$

I put

$u=\rho \cos\theta$

$v=\rho \sin \theta$

With this parameterization the integral, with some calculations, becomes

$\int \int \rho^2\sqrt{1+p^4} dpd0$.

I have two questions:

1. Is the procedure correct so far?
2. If so, how do I determine the definition ranges of $\rho, \theta$?

Comment: I think that $\rho \in [\frac 12, 1], \theta \in [0, 2\pi]$

Comment: I’d have used the parameterization $$\left(\frac{\cos\theta}y,y,\frac{\sin\theta}y\right)$$ from the start. The it is obvious the range of $y$ and $\theta.$

Comment: and with my parameterization are the intervals found okay?

Comment: I think your computation of $h_u$ and $h_v$ is wrong - there should still be square roots in the denominator.

Comment: I lift squared by the rule of the derivative of a fraction. Squaring the root is gone

Comment: No, it is not. You did it wrong. $$\frac{d}{du}\frac1{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}=\frac{-u}{(u^2+v^2)^{3/2}}.$$ If $h(w)=w^{-1/2}$ then $h’(w)=\frac{-1}2w^{-3/2}.$ Then apply the chain rule to $h(u^2+v^2).$

Comment: Sorry it's true! I had a moment of distraction. Now I correct the accounts and then edit the post

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: First $(u^2+v^2)^2=\rho^4,$ not $\rho^2.$ And $du\,dv=\rho\,d\theta\,d\rho.$ So I think you should get $$\iint \rho^5\,d\theta\,d\rho$$